# Black spots in app when running Samsung S3 - Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

We are developing one hybrid mobile application in phonegap and cordova.js. App is working fine in almost all android and iOS devices except Samsung S3 having android version 4.3. We are getting screens like below sometimes. Can anyone help[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same problem few days back. Finally Resolved it using this !!

Put this in the CSS. Then Lets Rock !!!

```
div.ui-overlay-a {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

if your getting this black patch when popup opens use following code
declare " data-overlay-theme='b' "  in your div and use the following code in your css file

div.ui-overlay-b {

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;
```

}